# upgrade postgresql 9.6 to 13 - pg_resetxlog.exe" failed: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade PostgreSQL 9.6 to 13. I have already installed PostgreSQL version 13 on my machine and am trying to use pg_upgrade. However I face the following error that I do not understand.

> check for "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_resetxlog.exe"
> failed: No such file or directory Failure, exiting

Could anybody please tell me how to handle this?

Here is the command prompt:

```
pg_upgrade.exe -d "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data" -D "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data" -b "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin" -B "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/bin"
```

Comment: The file in the error message does not exist on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

pg_resetxlog was renamed to pg_resetwal in version 10.  Of course recent versions of pg_upgrade know about that renaming, while older ones do not know about something that had not happened yet at the time they were written.  You are probably using the wrong version of pg_upgrade.  If you are upgrading to v13, you must use the pg_upgrade that comes with v13.